MIPI-LCD connector the same between Pine A64 version 1.0 MIPI DSI touchscreen Raspberry 4 model B?
Is the MIPI-LCD connector from the Pine A64 version 1.0 the same connector (compatible with) the MIPI DSI touchscreen connector on the Raspberry 4 model B? Will a touchscreen for the Pine A64 version 1.0 work with the Raspberry 4 model B?

ask the manufacturer
